# CSS: background-color and icon - inverting masks

Tags: html, css, mask

here is a tough one. Let's imagine I have `div`, with a specific size (`width` and `height`), and a `background-color: pink;`. Now let's say I have a icon, a png file (or svg or anything), and I want the image to "dig" into the background color.
In other words, I want the icon to be displayed in transparent, and the pink all around it. Like this:
[image: example]
It is just like the `mask-image` property, just the opposite.

---

### Details:

- There's no need about browser compatiblity (it's not for production use)
- I can't use Javascript nor JQ (html / css)
- And of course I can't edit the png file (to invert transparency and color ;))

Here are two PNG to match with the background-color:

[image: stackoverflow]
[image: pacman]

---

### Related:

- This is not like the png was simply a character: [codepen](https://codepen.io/huange/pen/rbqsD).
- This is not just using `mask-image`: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/quLo1064/)
- https://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/mask-image/
- https://alligator.io/css/masking-with-mask-image/
- https://codepen.io/yoksel/full/fsdbu/

---

Do you guys have any clue to achieve this behaviour?
Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: When downvoting, you might want to elaborate in the comment section, so I can learn what I can improve with this question ;)

Comment: Sounds like homework xD

Comment: :') No even close! I was digging into the `mask-image` property to try some stuff on my company's intranet, and I was like "hey, how can I invert this/do the opposite?"

Comment: This just sounds like asking someone to code it for you but with extra steps.

Answer (score -2):

You may want to use `filter: invert(1);` on the `image` when inside the `div`:

The image does not dig inside the div, but that visually works if the color behind the div is the same.
(I've added a different color on the body to illustrate that unwanted behavior)

```css
body{
  background: #ddd;
}

div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 140px;
  background-color: pink;
}

div img {
  /* You may want to add brightness(0) before invert for some images */
  filter: invert(1); 
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="img_container">
    <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/61/61072.png" />
  </div>
  <p>Original image:</p>
  <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/61/61072.png" />
</body>
```

Note that I didn't use your images because it's not only black and transparent.

Comment: I think “transparent” meant they actually want whatever is behind this to show through.

Comment: Ok your snippet looks exactly what I'm looking for. However, why an icon in another color than black won't work?

Comment: @4wk_ Try editing my snippet with the first image you provided. I can't on my phone.